# Sorting columns in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, populate

Currently I´m trying to create my first Joomla!-Component.
I have a table with some data and want to make the table sortable.
It works fine, but the default sort-direction is ASC, but I want to have DESC.

Here is my code from the model:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;


class KmListsModelKmLists extends JModelList
{
    public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true) {
        $options = array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData);
        $form    = $this->loadForm('kmlists', 'addrun', $options);
        if (empty($form)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $form;
    }

    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        if (empty($config['filter_fields'])) {
            $config['filter_fields'] = array(
                    'user','groupname','date','distance');
        }

        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    protected function populateState($ordering = 'date', $direction = 'DESC')
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        $ordering  = $app->input->get('filter_order', $ordering);
        $direction = $app->input->get('filter_order_Dir', $direction);
        echo "populateState: ".$ordering.' - '.$direction.'<br />';
        parent::populateState($ordering, $direction);
    }



    protected function getListQuery()
    {
        $db = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $requested_user = $app->input->get('user', 0, 'int');
        $requested_group = $app->input->get('group', 0, 'int');
    
        // Filter by user-id
        if($requested_user)
        {
            $query->where('U.id = '.$requested_user);
        }

        // Filter by group-id
        if($requested_group)
        {
            $query->where('G.id = '.$requested_group);
        }

        $query->from('#__kmlists_runs AS R');
        $query->innerJoin($db->quoteName('#__users') . 'AS U ON R.user = U.id');
        $query->innerJoin($db->quoteName('#__user_usergroup_map') . 'AS UGM ON UGM.user_id = U.id');
        $query->innerJoin($db->quoteName('#__kmlists_groups') . 'AS G ON UGM.group_id = G.joomla_group');

        // Sorting the table
        $ordering  = $this->getState('list.ordering');
        $direction = $this->getState('list.direction');
        $query->order($db->escape($ordering).' '.$db->escape($direction));
        echo "getListQuery: ".$ordering.' - '.$direction.'<br />';
    
        $query->select('R.*, G.name AS groupname, U.username AS username, G.color AS color, G.id AS groupid');

        return $query;
    }
}
```

The output of my two echo-commands are

> populateState: date - DESC
>
> getListQuery: date - ASC

Where does the ASC come from?

Comment: Just as an aside, you could just get it from $app->input. But it looks like the state is not actually being set correctly in the parent populateState(). I'd go debug there, it may be a bug.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the problem by myself. For testing, I changed the order before this post and it seems like Joomla! saved this non-default order in my session and therefore I thought this was the deault order. So it was my mistake :-(